# generic method to turn an `enum constant name` back into an `enum constant`

Tags: java, generics

How would the following method that happens to be named `reverse` be rewritten as a generic method that allows any enumerated type.

```
public class TestX {

    enum Gender { male, female }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", TestX.reverse("male").name());
        System.out.printf("%s\n", TestX.reverse("female").name());
    }

    static Gender reverse(String name) {
        for (Gender g: Gender.class.getEnumConstants())
            if (g.name().equals(name))
                return g;
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I tried (but does not compile at `T.class`):

```
<T extends Enum<?>> T reverse2(String name) {
     for (T t: T.class.getEnumConstants())
         if (t.name().equals(name)) return t; 
     return null; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite it as such?

Comment: Yes, I've tried.  I will post an attempt soon if there is no answer.

Comment: It would be good to post it, so that we know what you need help with and what to focus on in the answers.

Comment: `T.class` is one of the things generics can't do - because the same bytecode is used for every `T`. Passing the `Class<T>` in explicitly is a common workaround, as in Steve P.'s answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
// Every enum class extends Enum<ThisEnumClassName>. 
// Since we want T to be enum we must write it as "extends Enum"
// but Enum is also generic and require type of store parameters 
// so we need to describe it as Enum<T> which finally gives us - T extends Enum<T>
static <T extends Enum<T>> T reverse(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
    for (T t : clazz.getEnumConstants())
        if (t.name().equals(name))
            return t;
    return null;
}
```

If you want to make it generic you need specify from which Enum you want to get your values. Otherwise there is no way to find correct enym (unless you also put it somewhere in `name` like `full.package.name.of.YourEnum.VALUE`).

---

You can also consider using

```
Enum.valueOf(YourEnumClass.clazz, "ENUM_FIELD_NAME")
```

but this approach instead of returning `null` when enum will not have specified element will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the following would work:

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> T reverse(String name, Class<T> t_class) {
    for (T t: t_class.getEnumConstants())
           if (t.name().equals(name))
                 return t;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think `<T extends Enum<T>>` is a circular definition.

Comment: No, it's not.  Consider: `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, which you need for a generic list of objects that are `Comparable` to each other.

Comment: @broiyan: No.  All enum types inherit from java.lang.Enum which is a generic class.  When you write `public enum MyEnum`, MyEnum becomes shorthand for `Enum<MyEnum>`.  Therefore to write a bounded type parameter for a generic method that accepts an enum `public <T extends Enum<T>> void myMethod() {...}` is exactly what is required.

Comment: This works without the exception catching.  Since `T` is an `Enum<>` the `name()` call should not throw an exception.

Comment: @broiyan Good call.  Forgot about that.